# Multiple Java installs on Windows

Tags: java, windows, vista64

Can 32-bit and 64-bit Java be simultaneously installed on Vista x64?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, and in fact, this is the only way to get Java Webstart, as there is no 64-bit version.

Edit: Supposedly a 64-bit Java WebStart [will be available](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4802695) in Java 6u12.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that when you update Java, it never removes the old version of Java, you should be able to run 32 and 64 bit java at the same time without a problem.